# jQuery String concatenation '+' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation, string-interpolation

I have a jQuery statement

```
 $('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail('+data[i].email+')"></i>' );
```

Here if I click this icon then this function `copyEmail()` is called which takes a string as an argument and adds it to the clipboard.

But when I click on the icon I get an error in my console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

then I tried doing it this way

```
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail("'+data[i].email+'")"></i>' );
```

I got this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

The problem is that I'm not able to pass a string in function.

Can someone slove this for me ?

Comment: I don't believe your problem is in the posted code, please edit question and post the function 'copyEmail', and check the reported line number from the console where the SyntaxError comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail(\''+data[i].email+'\')"></i>' );
```

**Problem in your code was...**

When you call a function with string as an argument you do `someFunction('somestring');`, in your code you are missing the `''` wrapping the string.

So you need to wrap `data[i].email` with `' .. '`. I have wrapped the `data[i].email` with `''` but as there was already one pair so I had to escape it with `\`.

Comment: Can you explain to me what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i class=\"ion-email\" onclick=\"copyEmail(\"'+data[i].email+'\")\"></i>' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use "\" to avoid the errors, so you can make this:

```
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email"  onclick="copyEmail(\''+data[i].email+'\')"></i>' )
```

Edited

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wrap `data[i].email` with `'+ +'` at all in your function argument:

```
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail(data[i].email)"></i>' );
```

```js
var data = [{'email': '123@gmail.com'}, {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'}];
var i = 1;
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail(data[i].email)">Click To Test</i>' );

function copyEmail(email){
  console.log(email);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.searchDisplay').append(`<i class="ion-email" onclick="copyEmail('${data[i].email}')"></i>`);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You're better to give it an id, or another identifying attribute, and then add the onClick handler after appending it, when it's available in the DOM, along the lines of:

```
$('.searchDisplay').append('<i id="num' + i + '" class...></i>');
$('#num' + i).on('click', 
                 function () {
                     ...
                 });
```

Or hook into all of them at once by selecting the `.searchDisplay` class. 
You can use `$(this)` in the function to determine which one was clicked.